# How to add an onclick event to an img element created in javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically creates a table with the image and the name uploaded by the user, now i want to let the user choose which images he wants trough a onclick event, but once i upload an image the function "myfunction" runs without clicking the img

function handleFiles() {

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");

var fileList = inputElement.files; 

var NameFile = [];

for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){

NameFile=fileList[i].name;

var x = document.createElement("Table");
x.setAttribute("id", "galeria" + (i));
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

// imagens

```
var Img = document.createElement("tr");
Img.setAttribute("id", "ImgTr" +(i));
document.getElementById("galeria" +(i)).appendChild(Img);

var Imgz = document.createElement("td");
var img =document.createElement("img");

img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  img.height = 50;
  img.onload = function(){
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }

  img.onclick = myfunction(); // onclick event attateched to img 
  element

Imgz.appendChild(img);
document.getElementById("ImgTr" + (i)).appendChild(Imgz);
```

// files names

```
var y = document.createElement("tr");
y.setAttribute("id", "Tr" + (i));
document.getElementById("galeria" +(i)).appendChild(y);

var z = document.createElement("td");
var t = document.createTextNode(NameFile);
z.appendChild(t);
document.getElementById("Tr" + (i)).appendChild(z);

}
}


function myfunction(){
alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: For a start, change `img.onclick = myfunction();` to `img.onclick = myfunction;`. You don't want to assign the *result* of calling `myfunction()` to the onclick handler - you want to assign the function itself as the handler.

Comment: Ok i didnt even realized that, thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to @CertainPerformance

```
/.../

img.onclick = myfunction; // onclick event attateched to img 
element

/.../
```